# Eclipse exported project in Android Studio and add remote dependency in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have exported my Android project in Eclipse as gradle build files, and imported in Android Studio.

I have updated my Android Studio today to v0.6.0 which built on June 05, 2014.

As a remote dependency I have added AppCompat to the dependencies which works fine as expected.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

But when I try to add other libraries such as `SmoothProgressBar`, `actionbarsherlock`, `nineoldandroids` and etc, it fails. When I run the app it shows following in Gradle Build tab:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.1.
     Required by:
         :MyApp:unspecified
```

And when I sync project with Gradle file, it shows following in Gradle Sync tab:

```
Error:com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.1 (double-click here to find usages.)
```

I tried an empty new project and add remote dependency for mentioned libraries(Sherlock and etc) worked as expected. So `I guess I missed something in build.gradle` or any other solution?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Update to explain the answer:
To resolve your dependencies, you have to indicate in the gradle script which are the repositories to be used. You can use more repositories...

With the `support libs` (support and support-compact) it is not necessary, because the android plugin searches in your `androidRepository` and `googleRepository` downloaded with your SDK Manager.

Comment: can you expand your answer with saying the reason? Is a bug in the exported gradle file from Eclipse ?

Comment: @Ali I don't know what Eclipse exports. I've updated the answer explaining why gradle needs this part.